# How to remount a RAID 0 after a fresh install?

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

My server that holds all my music, tv shows, etc. stopped booting and after failing to get it running myself, I took it to a place and they reinstalled ubuntu on a different drive. I have 2 other drives in there combined in a RAID 0 that have all the media I want to stream, but I can't figure out how to mount them. I made the RAID with mdadm and I installed mdadm on my pc.

Running `sudo fdisk -l`  gives me this:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 55.45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 32.3 MiB, 33865728 bytes, 66144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 43.28 MiB, 45371392 bytes, 88616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 61.93 MiB, 64913408 bytes, 126784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 698.65 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Disk model: ST3750640NS     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5436eff4

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    1050623    1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 1465147391 1464094722 698.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 1465147391 1464094720 698.1G 83 Linux


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 596.18 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD6400AAKS-6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9DD06902-19ED-47CE-9911-116C40929E9F


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EFRX-68F
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3CD8FB5F-6919-4017-B136-91DDC562DD35




Disk /dev/loop8: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 65.22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 54.24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 247.93 MiB, 259948544 bytes, 507712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 99.45 MiB, 104267776 bytes, 203648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 9.3 MiB, 9465856 bytes, 18488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 295.73 MiB, 310079488 bytes, 605624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 81.89 MiB, 85843968 bytes, 167664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

dev/sdb and dev/sdc are my raided drives, but I can't figure out how to mount them. I've also used the "Discs" app in the desktop and I can see the drives and it says they're in a RAID, but I don't see a single RAID drive I can mount.

I also tried using `sudo mdadm --detail` with every dev/md# that seems likely I would have used when I maid it but keep getting back "no such file or directory."

What should I do to get my RAID back and mounted?

Comment: The two disks you’ve identified as being part of a RAID set are different sizes. What type of RAID were you using? JBOD? The error for each is a bit concerning, too … 

Answer (score 0):

So I got it mounted, I just don't know how I managed it. I downloaded and ran the command `sudo dmraid -ay`. It returned "no raid discs." I walked away for a few hours, didn't reset, and when I opened the Discs app, suddenly my RAID was there and I could mount it by clicking a button. I think the dmraid must have done it, even though it said it didn't find any raid discs.